# Firebase upload multiple Storage / Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, angularfire2

Can someone guide me to upload multiple images to Firebase at the same time?

What I'm trying to do is upload several images to Firebase Storage and save each reference in Firestore (in an array, for example). I have managed to do it but only with one image. I am using Angularfire Storage.

Here a stackblitz if you want to see it in detail: https://stackblitz.com/edit/upload-multiple-firebase

At this moment the aspect is the following:

In Storage it looks like this (note that the image is inside a folder with the same Firestore ID):
[image]

In Firestore it looks like this (note that the ID is the same as in Storage):
[image]

Here my code:

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FirebaseService } from './services/firebase.service';

export interface Test {
  imagenDestacada: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
downloadURL: Observable<string>;
selectedFile: FileList | null;
forma: FormGroup;
tests: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private storage: AngularFireStorage, private afs: AngularFirestore, private fs: FirebaseService ) { 
this.forma = fb.group ({
  categoria: ['myCategoria'],

})
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.mostrarImagenes();
}

detectFiles(event) {
  this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
}

uploadFile() {
  const myTest = this.afs.collection('test').ref.doc();
  console.log(myTest.id)

  const file = this.selectedFile
  const filePath = `${myTest.id}/name1`;
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
  const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

  this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();  

  task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      fileRef.getDownloadURL().toPromise().then( (url) => {
        this.downloadURL = url;

        myTest.set({
          categoria: this.forma.value.categoria,
          imagenes : this.downloadURL,
          myId : myTest.id
        })

        console.log( this.downloadURL ) 
      }).catch(err=> { console.log(err) });
    })    
  )
  .subscribe()
}

mostrarImagenes() {
  this.tests = this.fs.getTests();
}

}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="container py-4">

  <input type="file" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)">
  <button (click)="uploadFile()" class="btn btn-primary">UPLOAD</button>
  <div>{{ uploadPercent | async }}</div>
  <a [href]="downloadURL">{{ downloadURL }}</a>

  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-6" *ngFor="let test of tests | async">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ test.imagenes }}" width="100%">
        <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">My text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

tests: Observable<any[]>;

constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore ) { }

getTests() {
  this.tests = this.afs.collection('test').valueChanges();
  return this.tests;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `detectFiles` only set to detect 1 file.

1. Change it to handle all the selected file instead of `file[0]` only.
2. Change `selectedFile` to `selectedFileList` array instead.
3. Change `uploadFile` logic to loop through the `selectedFileList` and upload.

Comment: For the part of handling multiple files, you can refer to part of this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/file-uploads-in-angular-with-a-node-and-hapi-backend

Comment: Thanks, it's hard for me to understand it but I'm reviewing the link in detail. Thanks for the help.